# Create a mirror of all dependencies of Yocto-based project

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I have a Yocto (poky)-based project where I would like to avoid downloading all the dependencies from the internet. I have found the [PREMIRRORS](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#var-PREMIRRORS) variable that can be used to tell the build to get the dependencies from a local directory. The documentation does not, however, mention how to create such directory.

Is there some way to ask the build system to fetch all the packages to some place where they can be easily collected, or at least enumerate all the URLs so they can be mass-fetched?

Comment: You can look at this [mega manuel section](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#how-does-the-yocto-project-obtain-source-code-and-will-it-work-behind-my-firewall-or-proxy-server) for details on how to configure mirrors.

Answer (score 0):

See here please:
https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.6/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#getting-source-files-and-suppressing-the-build

The directory can be then used directly as a PREMIRRORS location.